# Python: urlopen - skip entry if any error occurs

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen

I was wondering if there was some sort of "Catch all" code for urlopen that would skip an entire entry in my for loop should any error in accessing the website occur.

Comment: use `try` and `except`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch exceptions with a `try/except` block:

```
# Python 3 example
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
from urllib.request import urlopen

for entry in entries:
    try:
         data = urlopen(...)
    except URLError, HTTPError:
         print("Something bad happened")
    else:
         # Process data get from the URL opened
         # If an exception has been catch, you won't 
         # enter in this else block
```

Comment: The code "works", as I do not get any errors when running it, but I'm not really sure if it's working because its potentially skipping any problems that come along, or if there simply aren't any errors, thus no 'activation' of the code.

Comment: You can try to add some `print` in the `else` block if you want to see if it executes it :)

Comment: @user3476845: to ignore all errors, catch `Exception` objects. URLError and HTTPError are not enough.